# fancybox image slider shows box on android browser

Tags: html, browser, fancybox-2

website: http://www.abdulhaiart.com

On my galaxy s3 android browser, the website shows a grey box ...i can't understand why

please help
im using this template: http://www.alessioatzeni.com/blog/brushed-template/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I had an android phone it would probably be easier for me to troubleshoot. But it may be a markup issue. You have several tags which look like `</br>` Try converting it to `<br />`

Comment: i noticed when i upload the original theme , it also had two grey boxes on android browser, so its not the </br>, i'll fix that though